# What do I need to purchase a vehicle from someone off of Craigslist?

Tags: car

Two questions
1) I'm planning on buying a car off of someone on Craigslist and this will be my first time buying a car, is there any paperwork or anything that I need? Should the person selling the car be providing all of this?

2) In the state of Florida, can I purchase a vehicle if I don't have a drivers license as long as I don't drive it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about requirements for purchasing a vehicle and not about Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair.

Comment: Is there another section of this site dedicated to vehicles?

Comment: If you'd like to ask this question in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/general-discussion), you might be able to get some help there.

Comment: Your state DMV/RMV website should be able to provide this information.